# Word for the broken bottom of a bottle

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Suppose if a bottle broke such that its head shattered but the bottom survived, something similar to in [this image](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/broken-bottle-green-26632163.jpg). I'm referring to such a shard(??) in my sentence but am not able to come up with an appropriate word to represent it.

> e.g. sentence - Squatting, he picked up the broken remains of the
>   bottle and raised the __________ as if making a toast

Searching has yielded the following options - cracked heel, shard, fragment but they do not feel fitting as they do not conjure that image. Is there a specific term that can be used ?

Comment: Picked up the jagged bottom half of a broken bottle and raised ***it*** as if making a toast...

Comment: I'd probably call it the "butt" or "heal", if "bottom" didn't quite do it.

Comment: Oops -- make that "heel".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this image:

(*[Source](https://sha.org/bottle/morphology.htm)*)

[image]

I would use the term **body**, however it probably makes more sense in context of the sentence to **base**.

Hopefully with this image in mind you can come to your own conclusion.

Hope this is helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

I would probably say "raised the bottle's ragged base, as if making a toast"

Comment: The most sensible option, but not really a fitting answer on a site aimed at linguists.

Answer (score 1):

with single word request:  **Shiv**

with your **terminology** tag in mind:  **Glassing**

**Glassing** is a physical attack using a glass or bottle as a weapon. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glassing)

and

9. informal to hit (someone) in the face with a glass or a bottle [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/glassing)

The most common method of glassing involves the attacker smashing an intact glass in the face of the victim. However the glass may be smashed before the attack, and then gripped by the remaining *base* of the glass or *neck* of the bottle with the broken shards protruding outwards.

If a broken bottle is used as such it would be a **shiv**. [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/shiv)

Answer (score 0):

A bottle may be likened to a [vessel](https://shop.drinkfinity.com/accessories/drinkfinity-vessel). So for dramatic effect, I'd call it a shattered [hulk](https://books.google.com/books?id=WDUEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA49&dq=shattered%20hulk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin1s6cj6TaAhVIfbwKHe-vBzoQ6AEIQTAE#v=onepage&q=shattered%20hulk&f=false).

> Squatting, he picked up the broken remains of the bottle and raised the [**hulk**](https://books.google.com/books?id=iLhYAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA107&dq=shattered%20hulk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin1s6cj6TaAhVIfbwKHe-vBzoQ6AEIOzAD#v=onepage&q=shattered%20hulk&f=false) as if making a toast.

~~~~~~~~~~~~

> [Vessel](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vessel) 1. a : a container (such as a cask, **bottle**, kettle, cup, or bowl) for holding something